# Problem installing Ruby on Rails Bundle on Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
la@la:~/myapp$ gem install json -v '1.8.6'

Fetching: json-1.8.6.gem (100%)

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.

la@la:~/myapp$
```

Comment: try `sudo gem install`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project's GEMFILE file. Edit this file and add this

```
gem 'json', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.6'
```

Save file and go to terminal then run

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

To install the gem in your system, you have be superuser.
To install the gem run it with sudo:

```
sudo gem install json -v '1.8.6'
```